# How do I change textbox font back to default and clear default text when click or tabbed to?

Tags: c#, fonts, textbox, default

In a C# Windows Form App, how do I programatically make it to when a user clicks (or tabs) on/(to) a textbox,  the default text is cleared and reverts the font styling back to windows default?

I am just doing a basic form for testing.  I am not going to include the code that I am using that fails, because I've tried so many different things.  I sort of need to get help filling in the blanks.  I will have the text in the textBox grey and italicized.  When the textbox is tabbed to or clicked the text needs to disappear and the font style and color need to be set back to windows default.  I have spent all day messing with this, and I know it should be simple but I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out.  SOS!  Most information I see on the web has ASP, HTML, and Java, but I cannot seem to stumble on a C# example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

I have searched the extensively and cannot find a good example written in C#.  I ran accross a page several days ago, but wasn't yet on the market for this, so I paid no attention to it and now I cannot find it again. I tried several methods and now I am all confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store a value to indicate that the text has been changed. I would consider creating a derived TextBox like the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a Windows TextBox control that displays placeholder text when the
/// control is empty.
/// </summary>
public class PlaceholderTextBox : TextBox
{
    private bool _set;
    private Color _valueForeColor;
    private Color _valueBackColor;
    private Font _valueFont;
    private Color? _PlaceholderForeColor;
    private Color? _PlaceholderBackColor;
    private Font _PlaceholderFont;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the text that is shown when the <see cref="TextBox"/> is empty.
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Description ("The text that is shown when the TextBox is empty.")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string PlaceholderText { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="Color"/> of the placeholder text.
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Description("The color of the placeholder text.")]
    public Color PlaceholderForeColor
    {
        get { return _PlaceholderForeColor ?? _valueForeColor; } 
        set
        {
            if (value == _valueForeColor)
                _PlaceholderForeColor = null;
            else
                _PlaceholderForeColor = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="Color"/> of the background when displaying placeholder text.
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Description("The color of the background when displaying placeholder text.")]
    public Color PlaceholderBackColor
    {
        get { return _PlaceholderBackColor ?? _valueBackColor; } 
        set
        {
            if (value == _valueBackColor)
                _PlaceholderBackColor = null;
            else
                _PlaceholderBackColor = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="Font"/> used by the control when displaying placeholder text.
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Description("the Font used by the control when displaying placeholder text.")]
    public Font PlaceholderFont
    {
        get { return _PlaceholderFont ?? Font; }
        set { _PlaceholderFont = value.Equals(Font) ? null : value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the foreground color of the control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="Color"/> that represents the control's foreground color.
    /// </returns>
    public override Color ForeColor
    {
        get { return _valueForeColor; }
        set
        {
            _valueForeColor = value;
            if(_set)
                base.ForeColor = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the background color of the control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="Color"/> that represents the background of the control.
    /// </returns>
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get { return _valueBackColor; }
        set
        {
            _valueBackColor = value;
            if(_set)
                base.BackColor = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the font of the text displayed by the control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="Font"/> to apply to the text displayed by the control. 
    /// The default is the value of the <see cref="Control.DefaultFont"/> property.
    /// </returns>
    public override Font Font
    {
        get { return _valueFont; }
        set
        {
            _valueFont = value;
            if(_set)
                base.Font = value;
        }
    }


    public PlaceholderTextBox()
    {
        _valueForeColor = base.ForeColor;
        _valueBackColor = base.BackColor;
        _valueFont = base.Font;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.GotFocus"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_set)
        {
            Text = String.Empty;
            base.ForeColor = _valueForeColor;
            base.BackColor = _valueBackColor;
            base.Font = _valueFont;
            _set = true;
        }

        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.LostFocus"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> that contains the event data. </param>
    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Text == String.Empty)
        {
            Text = PlaceholderText;
            base.ForeColor = PlaceholderForeColor;
            base.BackColor = PlaceholderBackColor;
            base.Font = PlaceholderFont;
            _set = false;
        }

        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really think the OP knows how to set the placeholder text and just needs to know that the `GotFocus` event exists. However, this is an elegant, total solution that the OP should definitely consider.

Comment: I was lying in bed last night reading this post.  This looks to be exactly like what i need.  I am at wqork now today.  i am not a programmer.  I took a little bit of C++ in college several years ago.  i can piece working C# together by the skin of my teeth with the help of you guys here on StackOverflow, and Google.  I have been reading through  some beginner tutorials for C# and i slightly understand many of the concepts.  I am just lost about where the placement of this code will go, and how to apply this class to my textbox.  i need someone to hold my hand on this a little more.  SOS!

Comment: @HoustoneD: I actually wrote a complete implementation of this class because it's really pretty useful. Please check out the update code in the answer. **To use**: Copy the entire class into a new file in your project and recompile the solution. Now open up the designer toolbox, and you should see a new section titled "<youproject> Components" with the PlaceholderTextBox control in it. You can now use the control just like a normal textbox, but you will have four additional properties in the Appearance section that let you control the placeholder text and appearance.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you sir.  I'll be giving this a shot soon.  I have a had a few drinks tonight and don't have the capacity to implement this at the moment.  I will probably wait until i am on on the clock monday to do this.  You are the man! thanks again.  i'll let you know if i have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Might the [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) event work for you?